# Tokenizer of UITextInput, what is it used for?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextinput

I'm implementing a custom text input view, which adopts `UITextInput` protocol, when using `UITextView`, double tap a word make the word selected, I wonder how `UITextInput` use its tokenizer to tokenize the string, by now I didn't see any difference with or without assigning a tokenizer for UITextInput by overwrite `[UITextInput -tokenizer]` method.

Answer (score 2):

It is used for things like keyboard navigation (when you have a hardware keyboard connected). For example, navigating between words while holding Option and using the arrow keys, going to start / end of line.

From Apple's Text Programming Guide for iOS:

> Tokenizers are objects that determine whether a text position is
>   within or at the boundary of a text unit with a given granularity.
>   When queried by the text input system, a tokenizer returns ranges of
>   text units with a given granularity or the boundary text position for
>   a text unit with a given granularity. Currently defined granularities
>   are character, word, sentence, paragraph, line, and document; enum
>   constants of the UITextGranularity type represent these granularities.
>   Granularities of text units are always evaluated with reference to a
>   storage or layout direction.
>
> The text input system uses the tokenizer in a variety of ways. For
>   example, the keyboard might require the last sentence’s worth of
>   context to figure out what the user is trying to type. Or, if the user
>   is pressing the Option-left arrow key (on an external keyboard), the
>   text system queries the tokenizer to find the information it needs to
>   move to the previous word.

More: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies.html